# How do I add a USGS topographic layer to Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've found a few resources but all the links are either dead or the information is outdated. I'd really just like to have an additional layer in my google maps window that shows the USGS topographic map layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `google.maps.ImageMapType` to add custom layer, just like this:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
 // Create map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 62.323907, lng: -150.109291},
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });
 
 // Replace this url with any url you want
  // It's actually a url template
 var tileUrl = "http://b.tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";

  // Create a new ImageMapType layer.
  var layer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    name: "stamen_terrain",
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      return tileUrl.replace("{x}", coord.x).replace("{y}", coord.y).replace("{z}", zoom);
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 20
  });

  // Register the new layer, then activate it.
  map.mapTypes.set("stamen_terrain", layer);
  map.setMapTypeId("stamen_terrain");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: This would give me a single overlayed tile, correct? What if I&#39;m doing a fully interactive map? Do I need to run this every time the map moves or zooms? Do I need to loop through it just to get a full view loaded?

Comment: No you do not need to run it on every zoom or move. No you do not need to loop through it to get full view.